# indefinitely running subscriber using Paho MQTT

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I want to use paho to indefinitely receive the inputs from the publisher. After making some research I found some examples of simple publisher (I also use Node-red MQTT node to send some readings) and subscriber. They are as follows:

Publisher:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

#Publisher
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883, 60)
client.publish("topic/test", "Hello World")
client.disconnect()
```

Subscriber:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

#Subscriber
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with the result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("topic/test")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.payload.decode()) 
    
client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("localhost",1883,60)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.loop_forever()
```

The problem is that subscriber doesn't print anything, if I run publisher. However if I add the:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
     print(msg.payload.decode())
     client.disconnect()
```

I got only one reading/message and after the script stops or disconnects, which is quite obvious. My goal is not to stop the subscriber, but being able to receive and process the further payload, i.e. keeping listening on the port.

Comment: Could be a buffering issue: try `python -u …`.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly for me. You can post your comment as answer and I will mark it as an answer. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: You publisher is also not great, it will only work for small messages payloads and for QOS 0. You have to run the event loop for anything else. See [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#single) for better option

Comment: Thank you! This publisher is not good for sure, I just used it as an example, as my main goal is to receive the payload from the Node-Red MQTT node, sending some payload from devices. Anyway, thank you for the useful link!

Comment: There are many client examples out there. The Python Paho test subscribers we wrote are at https://github.com/gambitcomminc/mqtt-stats or https://github.com/gambitcomminc/monitor-thresh